# reading that from serial port in c - array indexing issue

Tags: c, arrays, serial-port

I have some c code that reads from a serial port into a buffer continiously and when it has read 100 bytes it writes them over a websocket using the function `log_write()`. 
Some of the data is missing so I think I'm getting undefined behaviour. Is there anything obviously wrong with the code?

Specifcally on the lines below should I be adding a 1 to `rdlentotal`? Is it overwriting the last char of the previous read?

Also should I be null terminating the buffer after the last char that is read? How would I do this?

`rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf));
    rdlentotal += rdlen; /*keep track of total bytes read*/`

```
int rdlen=0, rdlentotal = 0;
char ibuf[1024];

memset(&ibuf[0], 0, sizeof(ibuf)); /*clear the buffer*/

while (1) {

    /*read from serial port*/
    rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf));
    rdlentotal += rdlen; /*keep track of total bytes read*/

    if (rdlentotal > 100) { /*when you have 200 bytes write the websocket*/
        log_write("%s", &ibuf); /*write to websocket*/
        memset(&ibuf[0], 0, sizeof(ibuf)); /*clear buffer*/
        rdlentotal = 0; /*rest byte counter */
        rdlen = 0;
    }

    if (rdlen < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "rdlen les than 0\r\n");
    }

}
```

Updated code suggestions from Chux:

```
static void *serial_logging_thread() {

    ssize_t rdlen = 0, rdlentotal = 0;
    char ibuf[1024 + 1];

    memset(&ibuf[0], 0, sizeof(ibuf)); /*clear the buffer*/

    while (1) {

        /*read from serial port write to log file*/
        rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf) - 1 - rdlentotal);
        rdlentotal += rdlen;

        if (rdlentotal > 200) { /*when you have 200 bytes write to file and websocket*/

            ibuf[rdlentotal + 1] = '\0'; /*null terminate*/
            log_write("%s", &ibuf); /*write to websocket*/

            memset(&ibuf[0], 0, sizeof(ibuf)); /*clear buffer*/
            rdlentotal = 0; /*rest byte counter */
            rdlen = 0;
        }

        if (rdlen < 0) {
            LOG("error reading serial port, rdlen less than 0\r\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Declaration for `log_write()`.

```
int log_write(const char *fmt, ... /* arguments */){
```

Comment: `read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf));` --> `read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf) - rdlentotal);`

Comment: Tell us please - can the stream of bytes have NULs in it?  If so, you are already broken, as chux hints at below.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything obviously wrong with the code?

Yes, see below.

> Specifically on the lines below should I be adding a 1 to `rdlentotal`?

No.

> Is it overwriting the last char of the previous read?

No.

> ... should I be null terminating the buffer after the last char that is read?

Yes, if `buf` is treated as a *string*.  Yet since input may have `'\0'` bytes in it, more robust code would treat `buf` as a character array and pass `buf` and its length used to the logging functions.  Also see [@Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577283/reading-that-from-serial-port-in-c-array-indexing-issue/47577687#comment82112760_47577283)

> How would I do this (null  terminate the buffer) ?

See #2 below.

---

Code has at least the following problems:

1. Buffer overrun possibility.

   ```
   // rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf));
   rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof(ibuf) - rdlentotal);
   ```
2. Assuming `log_write("%s", &ibuf);` is similar to `printf()`, code is attempting to print `ibuf`, which may not be a *string* and it is not certainly null character terminated.  Think of what happens if the first read was `sizeof(ibuf)` characters long.  Instead, insure space and append a null character.

   ```
   char ibuf[1024 + 1];  // add 1 here                   - 1 below
   ...
   rdlen = read(fd_joule, &ibuf[rdlentotal], sizeof ibuf - 1 - rdlentotal);
   ...
   ibuf[rdlentotal + rdlen] = '\0';  // Code is certain to have memory for the \0
   ...
   log_write("%s", &ibuf);  // The use of & here is likely not needed.
   ```
3. `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not `int`.  Use that type and check for errors *before* `rdlentotal += rdlen;`

   ```
   ssize_t rdlen = read(...
   if (rdlen == -1) {
     LOG("error reading serial port, rdlen less than 0\r\n");
     continue;
   }
   rdlentotal += rdlen;
   ```
4. More robust to use `size_t` for array lengths than `int`

   ```
   // int rdlentotal = 0;
   size_t rdlentotal = 0;
   ```
5. Minor: Comment does not reflect code.

   ```
   // if (rdlentotal > 100) { /*when you have 200 bytes write the websocket*/
   if (rdlentotal > 100) { /*when you have more than 100 bytes write the websocket*/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The comment above is correct. To further comment, you could corrupt the stack by overwriting memory past ibuf and unpredictable behavior and likely crash.